# Props change from object to undefined when pass to a component

Tags: reactjs, api, react-props

I have this onClick event that will show a modal. Within the event, I passed an argument (object) that I got from an API request to show on the modal

```
  <button onClick={() => {handleEdit(item)}}> Edit </button>
```

then I store the item on an useState so I can pass it to a component

```
  const [itemEdit, setItemEdit] = React.useState(null);
```

Then I create a variable that will handle the function for the onclick

```
  const handleEdit = (item) => {
            dispatch(setIsAdd(true)) //this is just to open the modal (useContext)
            setItemEdit(item)
  };
```

then I add the modal component and pass the item as props

```
  {store.isAdd && <ModalAddClass itemEdit={itemEdit} />}
```

the modal component looks like this

```
const ModalAddClass = ({ itemEdit }) => {
        console.log(itemEdit);
}
```

on the console.log, I got the object but it changes to undefined.

```
 {classes_aid: '10', classes_class_num: 'ertwe', classes_class_name: 'twetwert', 
 classes_teacher_incharge: 'retert', classes_num_students: '3456', …}

 ModalAddClass.js:20 undefined
```

Comment: Are you setting the itemEdit state in an effect hook anywhere? Sounds like its being reset on every render.

Comment: I only use useEffect when I fetch data from the API. I didn't use it on the itemEdit state. It is weird because I got the data then it becomes undefined

Comment: Maybe the API is being called more than once, with an invalid input the second time around, resulting in a null/undefined state?

Comment: Can you update your question to include all relevant code? A [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's difficult to say what is happening from these fragmented snippets.